# NSIS - How to run Java Application In NSIS?

Tags: java, nsis

I wanna run a java application through NSIS. My java program is called PropertiesReader.java which reads a property from a .config file.How can I do this? Also the output of java program (which in this case is the property value) is stored in some variable say property_value in java program. How can i access back the value of this variable in NSIS script?

Comment: NSIS = NullSoft Install System?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the NSIS srcipt, you can run Exec or ExecWait to run the "java" and pass the PropertiesReader.class as parameter to it. Your java program can write the property_value to a file which you can read back from the script.

[Here](http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~simhaweb/java/lectures/appendix/installer/install.html) is a link that has a heading "NSIS and Java". You can check that out.
Just make sure that the PropertiesReader.class file is in the classpath.

Comment: The link is dead.